# set Android Emulator Camera resolution

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Im trying to get the Feed of my 4K Webcam into the Camera of an Android Emulator but i'm having trouble getting the full Resolution. I have tried many Emulators but they all seem to have some specific max camera resolution set. On nox and Genymotion I get a max camera resolution of 640x480px, On KoPlayer i got 1280x720p, in Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD) i got 1280x960px and in Memu which was the best one so far I got 1920x1080p. However that resolution doesnt suffice for my purposes.
Does anyone know an Emulator which supports higher virtual camera resolutions? Or how to create a Virtual Device in AVD which supports higher resolutions?

I know there is

hw.camera.maxHorizontalPixels

and

hw.camera.maxVerticalPixels

but I dont know where to edit those properties.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated :)